# Accountid & PublicKey returns different transactions for 0.0.1261794

Tags: hedera-hashgraph, hashgraph

I am using hedera offical api in code, for accountid 0.0.1261794 getting 2 transactions only where as publickkey e2cc4c84391f5d9fd74dcf8199fb0bcd9c629f4d9aaa223649aad2814c56e6ba associated with 0.0.1261794 accountid, return more than 20 transactions.

Account API -
https://mainnet-public.mirrornode.hedera.com/api/v1/accounts?account.id=0.0.1261794

Transaction API (AccountId) -
https://mainnet-public.mirrornode.hedera.com/api/v1/transactions?account.id=0.0.1261794

Transaction API (PublicKey) -
https://mainnet-public.mirrornode.hedera.com/api/v1/transactions?account.publickey=e2cc4c84391f5d9fd74dcf8199fb0bcd9c629f4d9aaa223649aad2814c56e6ba

As from explorer it's showing only two transactions.
https://hederaexplorer.io/search-details/account/0.0.1261794

Thanks
Umang

Answer (score 0):

This other network explorer also confirms that only two transactions are associated with the account ID you provided: https://hashscan.io/#/mainnet/account/0.0.1261794

One possible reason for this behavior is that on Hedera the concepts of accounts and keys are separate. This means that:

- a key pair (private/public keys) can be associated with more than one account.
- an account can be multi-sig, meaning it can have multiple keys associated with it to authorize transactions. More details on this in the Hedera documentation: https://docs.hedera.com/guides/core-concepts/accounts#account-id

Answer (score 0):

/transactions doesn’t really support filtering by account.publickey we probably should have returned status code 400 instead of treating it as if it’s just /transactions.

This will be fixed. Thanks for highlighting the issue.